# SQL Server how to avoid Time Zone conversion in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, date-conversion

I have to retrieve rows between certain dates *Pacific Standard Time*, but the database has the date column stored as UTC. Currently, I do the conversion in the WHERE clause, but this takes a lot of time since I'm using a function in the WHERE clause and that causes a full table scan.

```
SELECT T.foo
FROM table T
JOIN .... ON ....
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,SWITCHOFFSET(T.start_date_utc,DATEPART(TZOFFSET, T.start_date_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))) BETWEEN '1/1/2018 00:00:00 AM' AND '2/28/2018 23:59:59 PM'
```

***Is there a better way to do this without the conversion function in the WHERE clause?***

- The query takes 30 minutes, but when I remove the `CONVERT` and just have `WHERE BETWEEN date1 AND date2` it runs much faster, 21 seconds.
- Other suggestions welcome of course if there is a better solution than date comparison with the conversion statement.

**Other Info:**

- I only have `CONNECT SQL` and `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permissions, so I **cannot** create any new tables, indices, etc.
- Without `SHOWPLAN` permissions, I can't see the *query execution plan* to check if it's something else causing the slow query. But since taking out the convert statement brings the time from 30 minutes to 21 seconds, I suspect it's that line.
- I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17
- Windows 7

**What I've tried:**

- I tried creating a common table and converting the date column before the main query, but that is still just as slow. Likely since the conversion still needs to happen on every row.

  `WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT T.Foo, 
  CONVERT(DATETIME,SWITCHOFFSET(T.start_date_utc, DATEPART(TZOFFSET, T.start_date_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))) as start_date_pst`)

Comment: Cannot you convert just the constants ("in the opposite direction")?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read Tibor's  discussion of [datetime datatype](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes). You make assumptions that are subject to runtime errors and make logic errors about the domain of the datetime datatype. 23:59:59 is not the maximum possible time portion of a datetime value. Also note that you don't need to include AM/PM when using 24hr time format - de-complicate your code.

Comment: @stickybit True! I guess I was stuck on one mindset I forgot to consider the obvious.

Comment: @Smor Thanks for the resource! Just started getting into SQL and there is lots to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach is to change your input to UTC. That is a one time operation and easier for SQL to filter on. Below are different ways to achieve same goal depending on your sql version.

```
-- 1
WHERE T.start_date_utc
     BETWEEN '1/1/2018 08:00:00 AM' /*PST to UTC*/
        AND '2/28/2018 07:59:59 PM' /*PST to UTC*/
-- 2    
WHERE T.start_date_utc
 BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, 8, '1/1/2018 00:00:00 AM'),  /*PST to UTC*/
    AND DATEADD(HOUR, 8, '2/28/2018 23:59:59 PM' /*PST to UTC*/

-- 3
WHERE T.start_date_utc
     BETWEEN SWITCHOFFSET('1/1/2018 00:00:00 AM', '-08:00') /*PST to UTC*/
        AND SWITCHOFFSET('2/28/2018 23:59:59 PM', '-08:00') /*PST to UTC*/


/*Avoiding hard coded values*/

-- 4
DECLARE @offset INT

 SELECT @offset = DATEPART(TZOFFSET, CONVERT(datetime,'1/1/2018 00:00:00 AM') AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') * -1

 WHERE T.start_date_utc
 BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, @offset, '1/1/2018 00:00:00 AM'),  /*PST to UTC*/
    AND DATEADD(MINUTE, @offset, '2/28/2018 23:59:59 PM' /*PST to UTC*/

-- 5        
WHERE T.start_date_utc
     BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'1/1/2018 00:00:00 AM')  AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' /*PST to UTC*/
        AND CONVERT(datetime,'2/28/2018 23:59:59 PM')  AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' /*PST to UTC*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're doing the time zone conversion against all of your data. Instead, figure out what the correct UTC timestamps should be once and then compare your data to that. Like so:

```
declare @startTimePST datetime = '1/1/2018 00:00:00 AM',
    @endTimePST datetime = '2/28/2018 23:59:59 PM';

declare @startTimeUTC datetime = @startTimePST 
    at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time' 
    at time zone 'UTC',
  @endTimeUTC datetime = @endTimePST 
    at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time' 
    at time zone 'UTC';

select @startTimePST, @startTimeUTC, 
    @endTimePST, @endTimeUTC

SELECT T.foo
FROM table T
JOIN .... ON ....
WHERE T.start_date_utc BETWEEN @startTimeUTC AND @endTimeUTC;
```

By way of exposition, I'm declaring variables and assigning values to them that represent your PST timestamps. I then convert those to UTC by way of a double use of the `at time zone` clause. Why two? The first one attaches the PST time zone to your time zone-less timestamps and then converts *those* to UTC. Once I have those endpoints, I'm able to use them directly in the query.